# When will ROS Indigo be Released?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) on a new system and discovered that ROS Hydro does not support it.  Instead, I see that [ROS Indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo) will support Ubuntu 14.04.  Thus, I'm wondering when it will be released.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172613/when-will-ros-indigo-be-released?/) by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2014-06-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The exact release date is not set, however ROS Indigo is available as beta right now -- http://www.ros.org/news/2014/05/ros-indigo-igloo-beta-available.html -- what that generally means is that there may still be more bugs than usual, there may still be some API-breaking changes pushed in over the next few weeks, and that not all packages are released yet. Most core things are released, but many third party packages are not (as of 6/2/2014, indigo has 537 packages, whereas hydro has 1325). You can see a list of packages available here http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2